# Bizarre problem on Chat and SEDE with "group by"

Tags: bug, chat, data-explorer

I am experiencing some bizarre problems when trying to build/edit queries on https://data.stackexchange.com/

### Confirmed to be firewall/proxy problem.

This started on SEDE, whenever I try to create a query with a Group By clause. For example, this trivial query works:

```
Select Id AS [VID], Name AS [VName]
from VoteTypes
```

but when I add a group by clause:

```
Select Id AS [VID], Name AS [VName], count (*)
from VoteTypes
group by Id, Name
```

I get the following (**note:**  *I get the same error if I have the group-by right - including the 'name' column - as well as when I get the group-by wrong....*):

[image: SEDE Error with Group By]

I went to Chat to whine about this, and discovered that I cannot type group by in chat either. Any time I try to submit a chat with that text it fails with 'unexpected error'.

I have tried a number of things, but it appears that I can type "group by" just so long as there is something other than a space immediately after the 'y' in 'by'.

[image]

Here is the difference bewteen having something after the 'y', and not:

[image]

I have tried rebooting, I have used both firefox and IE. This is on windows7.

When I get home I guess I can try a different computer.

### EDIT:

When I tried to add a comment to this post, I got :-) :

[image]

Comment: Obviously, it appears that I can type group by into a main post... and comment.

Comment: I would point a big finger in the direction of your (over-zealous) work proxy.

Comment: This appears to be a problem for me specifically.... others int he chat room succeed.

Comment: You have to group by id and name, that's your mistake.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - of course.... ;-) but if I miss things like that I get an actual error message..... The problem is that I cannot even synta check things ;-)

Comment: @TimStone - I fear you may be right ..... and I only work for a small company with a three letter name ;-) I...B...M.... let me get that fixed quickly... ;-)

Comment: You group by ... poorly.

Comment: @Won't I won't defend the actual SQL, it's terrible, but that is just the small-self-contained-example I was able to reduce things down to (from a much larger multi-join query on posts, votes, users, etc.). That SQL is a measure if my frustration, not my ability ;-)

Comment: If anyone is interested ... I found a workaround for SEDE: [See the --firewall-fix](http://data.stackexchange.com/code%20review%20stack%20exchange/query/161292/bountifulii)

Comment: You group/r/nby ... well.

Comment: @Won't thank you, and, as a test, I am not at home and I can type group by without any problems.... ;-) (from the same physical laptop, just not behind the same firewalls).